# Input String is not in the correct format

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to read values from a text file into an array. This is a simple issue but even though I feel as though I've typed the code exactly as it is in my book, the code will not run without giving the error "input string is not in the right format" 
visual studio shows this in the output tray:

```
'CS_TotalSales.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: CS_TotalSales.vshost.exe): Loaded 'c:\users\dakota\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\CS_TotalSales\CS_TotalSales\bin\Debug\CS_TotalSales.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'CS_TotalSales.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: CS_TotalSales.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Accessibility\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Accessibility.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
 A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

I am unsure what any of the above means, although Im wondering if perhaps there has been a typo in my book. Below is the code, what could cause this error?

```
 //declare array and size variables
            const int SIZE = 7;
            decimal[] salesArray = new decimal[SIZE];

            //declare a counter
            int index = 0;

            try
            {
                //decalre and initialize a streamreader object for the sales file
                StreamReader inputFile = File.OpenText("Sales.txt");

                while (index < salesArray.Length && !inputFile.EndOfStream)
                {
                    salesArray[index] = int.Parse(inputFile.ReadLine());
                    index++;
                }

                //close the file
                inputFile.Close();

                //add sales to listbox
                foreach (int sale in salesArray)
                {
                    salesListbox.Items.Add(sale);
                }

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```

Comment: Check your source file. [int.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19(v=vs.110).aspx) will throw the `System.FormatException` error. You probably have a line with a trailing space or something along the lines.

Comment: `salesArray[index] = int.Parse(inputFile.ReadLine());` try by change this line to `salesArray[index] =Convert.ToInt32(inputFile.ReadLine().Trim());`

Comment: Like @Nathan said, and if that's the case consider trimming the return value from `inputFile.ReadLine()`.

Comment: can you show same sample data in the file?

Comment: If you put a try catch around the parse, you will be able to output the line causing the problem.  Also consider using(StreamReader) instead of manually closing the stream.

Comment: Side comment: You declared the array as `decimal`, but then are parsing the input file as integers... are you sure all the lines in `Sales.txt` are integers, or did you mean to use `Decimal.Parse()` instead?

Comment: @LeandroTaset here is the information Im trying to put int the array
1245.67
1189.55

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is the one causing the exception:

```
salesArray[index] = int.Parse(inputFile.ReadLine());
```

There is at least one line in your input file `Sales.txt` which cannot be parsed as an integer. Maybe a blank line, or some extra characters which make it an invalid integer. Perhaps there is a number with a dot (not an integer) or something else.

Use the `TryParse()` method instead, and check if there was an error in attempting to parse the line. Try changing this bit:

```
int number;
while (index < salesArray.Length && !inputFile.EndOfStream)
{
     if (Int32.TryParse(inputFile.ReadLine(), out number))
        salesArray[index++] = number;
}
```

Comment: The numbers I am trying to add have decimal points in them!! The decimal points are what was causing the exception! I hadn't thought of that! Thank you!